# How to configure DispatcherType's for SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot (2.1.5) application which uses the `SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration` feature. During registration of `DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean` only  `REQUEST`, `ASYNC`, `ERROR` `DispatcherTypes` are set. But I need `FORWARD` and `INCLUDE` as well.

The property **`security.filter-dispatcher-types`** from Spring Boot 1.x no longer works.

I can work around the problem by "overwriting" the `DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean` as follows:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(name = DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME)
@Primary
public DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean customSecurityFilterChainRegistration(SecurityProperties securityProperties) {
    DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean registration = new DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean(DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
    registration.setOrder(securityProperties.getFilter().getOrder());
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(allOf(DispatcherType.class));
    return registration;
}
```

But that doesn't seem like a very elegant solution to me.

Is there a way to configure this for Spring Boot 2.1.x explicit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `spring.security.filter.dispatcher-types`, see [Spring Boot 2.0 Configuration Changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Configuration-Changelog).